# Возможно ли сделать символ большим, не увеличив при этом пустое пространство внутри контейнера?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь максимально простыми средствами сделать некую круглую "лампочку", для этого в коде страницы написал •, а в CSS создал стиль .lamp {font-size:300%;}. Проблема в том, что чем больше становится "лампочка", тем больше "раздувается" ее контейнер, плюс съезжает вертикальная ориентация с соседним текстом. Как лучше всего сделать подобный трюк?

[Картинка http://puu.sh/mNKim/99011932b4.png](http://puu.sh/mNKim/99011932b4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно задать высоту линии.

```
.lamp {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

"Раздувает" именно line-height, корректировать нужно его.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось. Добавил еще vertical-align:top; для выравнивания.

Comment: @Keroronsk всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы контейнер не "раздувался" ему нужно указать фиксированную высоту.
Вот пример:

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lamp {
  font-size: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Текстовое <span class="lamp">•</span> сообщение
</div>
```